# Custom site content list

Tags: 2010, list, list-view, custom-list

I have a subsite for our meetings. On the first page of this subsite I would like to create a list of urls to all the meeting sites created within that meeting subsite. Is there a way to make this an automated process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your possibilities would depend on the type of solution you plan to put in place - no-code/ code-based (that is compiled code, e.g. via Web part), or in the middle (e.g. JavaScript ECMA in a CEWP). Each of these offer differ alternatives, basically:
1. Code-based - most obvious - custom web part enumerate based on Template Id of the meeting workspaces (below an excerpt from the actual webtemp*.xml where SharePoint 2010 stores all templates - you must know by now there are multiple types MPS#0, MPS#1, etc.)

```
<Template Name="MPS" ID="2">
    <Configuration ID="0" Title="Basic Meeting Workspace" Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stmw.png" Description="A site to plan, organize, and capture the results of a meeting. It provides lists for managing the agenda, meeting attendees, and documents." DisplayCategory="Meetings" SupportsMultilingualUI="FALSE" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="1" Title="Blank Meeting Workspace" Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stbm.png" Description="A blank meeting site for you to customize based on your requirements." DisplayCategory="Meetings" SupportsMultilingualUI="FALSE" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="2" Title="Decision Meeting Workspace" Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stdm.png" Description="A site for meetings that track status or make decisions. It provides lists for creating tasks, storing documents, and recording decisions." DisplayCategory="Meetings" SupportsMultilingualUI="FALSE" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="3" Title="Social Meeting Workspace" Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stsm.png" Description="A site to plan social occasions. It provides lists for tracking attendees, providing directions, and storing pictures of the event." DisplayCategory="Meetings" SupportsMultilingualUI="FALSE" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="4" Title="Multipage Meeting Workspace" Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stmm.png" Description="A site to plan, organize, and capture the results of a meeting. It provides lists for managing the agenda and meeting attendees in addition to two blank pages for you to customize based on your requirements." DisplayCategory="Meetings" SupportsMultilingualUI="FALSE" >    </Configuration>
 </Template>
```

The 2nd option would be using the dedicated SOAP web service as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff764949(v=office.12).aspx - not the most recomanded way, particularly moving forward 2013.

The 3rd alternative using Client-Side Object Model you would actually follow the same concept as with the 1st option via Javascript - difference being that you do not need to compile/deploy nor ask Farm admin to deploy it for you  -an example accessing all properties of an SPWeb http://www.stefan-walter.net/show-edit-web-properties-javascript-client-side-object-model/

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom webpart and through [SharePoint object model](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Category/sharepoint-object-model-7.aspx) read all the meeting sites and show it in a gridview. This way i feel you can do this.

Comment: These are both very good answers. I am going to try both and see which one works better.

Answer (score 1):

An approach I have used for similar requirements is to use the list as the start point.  So add the meeting to the list and then have workflow provision the site and populate the list with a link to the new site.